# Parse specific "Place" data from twitter search api

Tags: python, twitter, geolocation

I am trying to parse out some information in the "Place" field from the Twitter search API. There is a bunch of information stored in "Place":
['country_code'] ['url'] ['country'] ['place_type'] ['city']['coordinates']['full_name'] etc.......

I am specifically interested in parsing out the ['full_name'] attribute, but unsure as to how I would specifically parse out this (or any) single (or specific) attribute from the place field.

Here is my code:

```
import twitter

CONSUMER_KEY = 'KEY'
CONSUMER_SECRET = SECRET
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'SECRET'
auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
print twitter_api
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q='TheInterview', count =10)

for tweet in search_results['statuses']:
            # some me the tweet, jerry!
            print "        Tweet from @%s Date: %s Place: %s" % (tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8'),tweet['created_at'],tweet['place'])
            print "        ",tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'),"\n"
```

Here is an example full response which I want to cut down:

```
Tweet from @RhianneCx Date: Fri Jan 02 16:23:49 +0000 2015 Place: {u'country_code': u'GB', u'url': u'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/51e3c0bc6be3dc6e.json', u'country': u'United Kingdom', u'place_type': u'city', u'bounding_box': {u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[-1.2495102, 52.6148717], [-1.2088435, 52.6148717], [-1.2088435, 52.6416566], [-1.2495102, 52.6416566]]]}, u'contained_within': [], u'full_name': u'Kirby Muxloe, England', u'attributes': {}, u'id': u'51e3c0bc6be3dc6e', u'name': u'Kirby Muxloe'}
         Kim Jong Un gets bootay #TheInterview
```

Comment: Which python wrapper of twitter are you using?

Comment: I have just used import twitter, and accessing directly (updated above)